# Network activity indicator and beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

Tags: ios

I'm downloading content from a server and if the user switches my app to the background I continue the download by using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`.

I've noticed that the network activity indicator in the status bar goes away when my app goes to the background, but will reappear if the app switches back to the foreground.

I presume the OS is doing this automatically?
I was a bit surprised as I thought it might be an Apple iOS GUI user requirement that the user is always informed by the activity indicator if there is some network activity occuring.
But apparently that can't be the case?

Is there a way I can make the activity indicator continue to show in the status bar when the app is downloading in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no un-jailbroken way you can show the activity indicator for an app that's not currently in the foreground.

It's supposed to show activity for the app the user is currently using - they shouldn't have to worry about stuff in the background.